# CountA returns 0, WorksheetFunction.CountA returns 1

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In the debug window, the following expressions all return one.

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells(4 + (i - 1) * rows_per_record, 28) & ":" & Cells(5 + (i - 1) * rows_per_record, 58))

Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(n).Cells(4 + (i - 1) *  rows_per_record, 28) & ":" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(n).Cells(5 + (i - 1) * rows_per_record, 58))
```

In this particular case, the range is AB60:BF61, which is confirmed in debug window.

In the worksheet, while the script is paused, I enter in a cell `=CountA(AB60:BF61)` and the result is 0, which is what it should be.

Any explanation will be greatly appreciated.

Windows 7, Excel 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.

Correct Syntax:

`Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA (Range(Cells(4 + (i - 1) * rows_per_record, 28), Cells(5 + (i - 1) * rows_per_record, 58)))`

Your code is counting each argument that is not an empty string.  The only argument is a colon surrounded by the two empty cell values.

`Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(n).Cells(4 + (i - 1) * rows_per_record, 28) & ":" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(n).Cells(5 + (i - 1) * rows_per_record, 58))`

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking that the colon should be a comma. I'll run some tests.

Comment: If it was a comma it would be considered two separate arguments; one for each cell.  Using Range will extend the range between the cells.  But let me know, just in case..lol.

Comment: Yes, you are always counting **1** regardless of the actual count because you are concatenating together the cell value from the first, then a colon then the cell value from the last. You are essentially counting a single string which will always be **1**. YOu would have to Evaluate it as a worksheet function using the cell addresses concatenated with the colon to use it this way. By using Range and supplying hte upper-left and lower-right separated by a comma, I count the whole range.

Comment: You worded that much more better that I did. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have the answer and one version of the correct syntax in another response. Here is an alternate:

```
dim c as long
with ThisWorkbook.Sheets(n)
    c = Application.CountA(.range(.Cells(4 + (i - 1) * rows_per_record, 28), _
                                  .Cells(5 + (i - 1) * rows_per_record, 58)))
    debug.print c
end with
```

The [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) is constructed by supplying the upper-left and lower right corners with two [Range.Cells properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx). The parent worksheet is referenced through the [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx).

Comment: I should have wrapped my ranges inside a With block and qualified them.